# Compare and split a string using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs.

I need to compare two strings and to print **common** words from both strings using angularjs.

My angularjs code is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
    {name1: 'aaaa',name2: 'aaaa'},
    {name1: 'abc',name2: 'abcde'},
    {name1: 'aabbcc',name2: 'aabbdd'}
  ];
});
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names ">
        <td>{{x.name1}}</td>
        <td>{{x.name2}}</td>
        <td ng-if='x.name1 == x.name2'>{{x.name1}}</td>
        <td ng-if='x.name1 != x.name2'><!--Output--></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

expected output:

```
name1   name2   output
aaaa    aaaa    aaaa
abc     abcde   abc
aabbcc  aabbdd  aabb
```

I've used ng-if for first set. Then what to do for remaining set of values?? Is this possible by using angularjs alone??

Comment: you will atleast have to write the logic for substring comparison or contains or something like that... the current code does not have any of that yet

Comment: You should re-tag your question. This has nothing to do with angular. It's a pure JavaScript, and even algorithmic question. You should also provide a better specification of "common". Are you looking for common characters at the same position? etc.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking that just because you're using a framework, that every bit of your code has to utilize it. JavaScript has built in methods for splitting strings.

Comment: @JBNizet but there are potential angular solutions like using a filter which of course would be in addition to the string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this vanilla js code:

```
function getIntersection(s1, s2) {
  var result = '', i, map = {};

  for (i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
    map[s1[i]] = (map[s1[i]] || 0) + 1;

  for (i = 0; i < s2.length; i++)
    map[s2[i]] = (map[s2[i]] || 0) + 1;

  for (var key in map)
    if (map[key] > 1)
      result += key;

   return result;
}
```

I've integrated this into angular, usnig a *custom filter*:

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/b95y5m46/